# Does the VGA port on a laptop need drivers to function?

Tags: motherboard, gpu, vga, laptop-repair

I have an old HP dv4 laptop with an unresponsive motherboard (only flashed the caps lock when turned on). It also needed a new screen but I don't care about that part.

I sent it to an unofficial repair shop - they reflashed the BIOS and got it to be seemingly responsive, (caps/num/scroll lock lights, ctrl-alt-del seem to all be responsive when powered on), but I could get absolutely no video output whatsoever from it on either the HDMI or the VGA port (and obviously not on the broken screen).

I was charged a full repair and was told that it is working properly now.

When I sent it back, they insisted that the lack of VGA output is merely a software/drivers issue (i.e. the port needs to be turned on from Windows), and if I install a working laptop screen, I would see video immediately.

I find that hard to believe, and I feel that it is a hardware/gpu issue, because with every other laptop I have tried, the VGA port turns on immediately once the computer is turned on and displays the BIOS messages (press Fx for setup, etc.) I just need to know that this is the case before I take it up further with them.

Comment: VGA output should work before any OS is loaded, so drivers are not needed. Check you bios settings and be sure vga out (or similar) is enabled if it has it.

Comment: The issue is the screen is broken so I can't see any video out of the machine.

Comment: Every laptop I have owned output video to the vga port when a monitor is connected, bios screen also. I have seen some you have to change a bios setting for this to work, which if this is your case, you cannot.

Comment: Laptops typically do not automatically output a signal from the external VGA port.  Apparently to save power or reduce EMI, you have to explicitly enable the external VGA output.  Typically there is a function key to enable this VGA output.